# cmd error appears when i am starting the code. i think it is my player1rect that is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, rect, pong

i am trying to program Pong and i am so far:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

FPS=30
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

size = width, height = 1280, 648
speed = [8, 8]
DISPLAYSURF=pygame.display.set_mode((size),0,32)
background=pygame.image.load('bg.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

UP='up'
DOWN='down'

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

player1 = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
player1rect = player1.get_rect()
player1x=14
player1y=323
direction=None

def move(direction, player1, player1x, player1y):
    if direction:
        if direction == K_UP:
            player1y-=5
        elif direction == K_DOWN:
            player1y+=5
    return player1, player1x, player1y

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(background,(0,0))

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(player1,(player1x,player1y))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            direction = event.key
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if (event.key == direction):
                direction = None
    player1, player1x, player1y = move(direction, player1, player1x, player1y)

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]    

    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

but when i am trying to open it in CMD this error appear

```
  File "C:\Users\Gustav\Documents\Pong\Pong.py", line 58
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
                                    ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

i do not think that it can load the 'player1rect'. because i wan´t the 'ball' and 'player1' to collide so i did make a rect for them each, but it don´t seems it´s working. so in all i wan´t to get the error disappear.

Comment: When it says "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation", I'm not sure how you get from there to "do not think that it can load the 'player1rect'"... Python's error messages are generally pretty good at pointing out where the error lies (well, ok, better than some other languages, anyway...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem with indentation - use tab or 4 spaces, not both. You mixed tabs and spaces near line 58.

I checked your code - it work fine. So test your indentation or use editor which can change tabs to 4 spaces (or 4 spaces to tabs)